# How do you calculate this product $\mathbb{Z}_6\times\mathbb{Z}_6$

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

> How do direct product (Cartesian product) of $$\mathbb{Z}_6\times\mathbb{Z}_6$$

I need to know if this product is a direct integral domain (ring integrity).

Comment: What exactly are you looking for?

Comment: This is the group (set) of elements of the form $(a,b)$ with $a,b \in \Bbb Z_6$. Is that all you wanted to know?

Comment: As additive groups, or as rings?

Comment: @anomaly I need to know if this product is a direct integral domain (ring integrity).

Comment: @MarkBennet As rings...

Comment: Is $\mathbb Z_6$ an integral domain?

Comment: @MarkBennet No, because $\overline2\cdot\overline3=\overline0$

Comment: @marcelolpjunior: Consider the product of $(a,0)$ and $(0,b)$.

Comment: @Bungo $\Longrightarrow (a,0)\times (0,b)=(a\cdot 0, 0\cdot b)=(0,0)$, but in this case $(a,0)\neq0$ and $(0,b)\neq0$?

Comment: @marcelolpjunior: Right, $(a,0)\times(0,b) = (0,0)$ even if $a$ and $b$ are nonzero. This shows that the direct product $R \times S$ can't be an integral domain even if $R$ and $S$ are.

Comment: Also note that $(2,2)\cdot (3,3)=(0,0)$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

write $Z_6$ as ${0,1,2,3,4,5}$ then $\mathbb{Z}_6\times\mathbb{Z}_6$ looks like {$(0,0) , (0,1) , (0,2)...(0,5), (1,0), (1,1), ... (1,5), (2,0)...(2,5), (3,0),...(3,5) .... (5,5)$} in total $36$ such tuples.

Answer (score 1):

The best answer that I can give you is this:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Direct_product_of_groups